# Missing essential plugins: com.intellij.java com.intellij.java.ide

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

[image]

I was using Intellij 2020.2 and today suddenly after restarting my PC, I am facing this error.

Missing essential plugins:

com.intellij.java
com.intellij.java.ide

Please reinstall IntelliJ IDEA from scratch.

I've tried reinstalling Intellij from scratch, as the error says, but nothing changes.

Comment: Try to manually delete all [IDE directories](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) before reinstalling. If the problem remains please contact IntelliJ support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)

Comment: Also, try using the 2022.2 build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download